# trying to get a bot to send a photo using pytelegrambotapi but i keep getting the filenotfounderror

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

So, I am a super beginner at coding and Python who is trying to make a telegram bot for my friend's upcoming birthday. I know my basics here and there, so please be nice! I am using [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/0.3.0/) and **Replit**. Basically, I want the bot to send some images after a command has been correctly triggered. I'm copying the code for the image path correctly but somehow this error keeps popping up. Help!

```py
    photo1 = open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\bday\IMG_2201.PNG", 'rb')
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['photo'])
    def msg4(message):
      bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
```

[my code on replit and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBRHE.jpg)

[what i think im supposed to code for my bot to send an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXoj9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**There's the problem with your path python support  `//`**

> Change you path to this
> `C://Users//User//Desktop//bday//IMG_2201.PNG`
>
> if you give the correct path then this code will work for you

```
photo1 = open("C://Users//User//Desktop//bday//IMG_2201.PNG", 'rb')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['photo'])
def msg4(message):
  bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
```